# ImproperlyConfigured: django-multilingual-ng

Tags: django, plugins, settings, multilingual

I want use django-multilingual-ng on django 1.4, with postgresql 8.4, on debian squeeze
but when activate this plugin :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_multilingual_ng-0.1.45-py2.6.egg
/multilingual/settings.py", line 29, 
in <module> "Only found: %s" % (mcp, found) 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: django-multilingual-ng 
requires the 'multilingual.context_processors.multilingual' context processor. 
Only found:  django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth,
django.core.context_processors.debug,django.core.context_proc
essors.i18n,
django.core.context_processors.media,django.core.context_processors.static,
django.core.context_processors.tz,django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages
```

I don't understand, i have install django-multilingual-ng, configure settings.py, but he raise this exception.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Show us `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Answer (score 0):

Add `multilingual.context_processors.multilingual` to settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Comment: thanks but this condition is already complete, and not resolve problems.

Comment: I implement my self model internationalization, for all table to internationalize i have an other table type i18n for all elements to translate